# How to detect when a JavaScript object variable is accessed?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to debug some javascript code and I need to know when a particular variable on an object is accessed/run. Not when it changes, but when the script runs to a particular variable.

Is there a way?

Comment: Use breakpoints in the Chrome inspector instead of trying to do this.

Comment: I'm using an external JS library(PIXIJS), which is responsible for taking a texture and drawing it to the stage, my problem is that it is drawing it incorrectly and I want to know how it is doing the draw.

The problem is that I don't know what function within PIXIJS that draws my texture, so I'm hoping by putting a watch or something on my texture, I can pinpoint what process is doing this

Using breakpoints means I already know where the code is being executed, but I don't

Comment: it depends on how it's called, but you can create an object with a custom `.valueOf()` or `toString()` method that, say, logs `arguments.callee.caller` when invoked by assessing the var.

Comment: Objects do not have "variables". They have "properties".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Reflect.apply()` or `Proxy.handler()`

```js
const o = {
  abc: function() {
    return 123
  },
  def: function() {
    return "456"
  }
}

for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(o)) {
  if (typeof value === "function") {
    let fn = o[key];
    Object.assign(o, {
      [key]: function(...args) {
        // do stuff
        console.log(key + " proxy arguments:", args);
        return Reflect.apply(fn, o, args);
      }
    })
  }
}

console.log(o.abc(1, 2, 3), o.def(4, 5, 6));
```

```js
const o = {
  abc: function() {
    return 123
  },
  def: function() {
    return "456"
  }
}

for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(o)) {
  if (typeof value === "function") {
    Object.assign(o, {
      [key]: new Proxy(o[key], {
        apply: function(o, thisArg, args) {
          // do stuff
          console.log(key + " proxy arguments:", args);
          return args;
        }
      })
    })
  }
}
  
console.log(o.abc(1,2,3), o.def(4,5,6));
```

Comment: neat. for function "variables" how does this differ from plain old wrapping the methods?

Comment: @dandavis Not any difference that am aware of. Included both `Proxy` and `Reflect.apply()` approach. The first assigns the property as a `Proxy`, the second calls the original function with `this` set to original or other object.

Comment: Sure, but this assumes that he has control over the object in question, and can arrange for the code in the third-party library to use the proxy instead of the backing object.

Comment: @torazaburo  Try not to assume anything, here. If OP  gets or is returned an object, is apparently not aware of which function on object performs which task. `Reflect.apply()` calls function with `this` set to an object. `Proxy` approach replaces the original function with `Proxy` object. Can get `arguments` at each. Could certainly be further adjusted and improved. OP could also convert the functions to strings and read each line to determine what is being called. Read _"I need to know when a particular variable on an object is accessed/run."_, was at stacksnippets since.

Comment: @torazaburo Missing something, here, as to original Question?

Comment: I am not assuming anything, you are. Proxies do not "replace" the original function; they **wrap** it.

Comment: @torazaburo Perhaps am missing something. Does not `Object.assign()` with first parameter as original object overwrite original property of object where parameters 1,N is object having same property? Or is the pattern still wrapping the original property and function, as `this` is same?