# How to intercept a known property value assignment of an unknwon object created using literal notation

Tags: javascript, object, monkeypatching

This question is a continuation of another I asked here: [How to intercept and modify a specific property for any Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42611719/how-to-intercept-and-modify-a-specific-property-for-any-object/44103125)

This is a method used to intercept any object's property of a certain name with the objective of changing the value or do a certain action when it is assigned or read:

```js
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "my_property", {
    set: function (value) {
        this._value = value;
    },
    get: function () {
        return "changed";
    }
});

var some_object = {};

some_object.my_property = "unchanged";


document.body.innerHTML += some_object.my_property;
```

```html
My property value is:
```

While that method is working fine for values assigned to or read from properties after the object has been created, example:

```
var some_object = {}; // or new Object()
some_object.some_property = "some_value"; // triggers setter
console.log(some_object.some_property);   // triggers getter
```

It won't trigger the getter and setter if the property has been initialized together with the object using literal notation, like so:

```
var some_object = {some_property: "some_value"}; // does not trigger setter
console.log(some_object.some_property);          // does not trigger getter
```

How can I adapt the previous strategy so that it can also work with the literal notation or is there a different way of achieving this using a completely different method? Perhaps by intercepting the creation of any object through literal notation, similar to monkey patching the Object.create() function?

Keep in mind that this is only to target a property of a known name on any unknown object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way I know of to achieve the effect you're looking for. An assignment with `=` will cause your object to go through the Prototype chain and use the `get` method on the Object prototype. However, a literal assignment will place it directly on your new object. It's the rules of Javascript. For more information I'd suggest reading You Don't Know JS, This & Object Prototypes, Chapter 5, specifically the [Setting & Shadowing Properties](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch5.md#setting--shadowing-properties) section.

Relevant part:

> We will now examine three scenarios for the myObject.foo = "bar"
>   assignment when foo is not already on myObject directly, but is at a
>   higher level of myObject's [[Prototype]] chain:
>
> 1. If a normal data accessor (see Chapter 3) property named foo is found
>      anywhere higher on the [[Prototype]] chain, and it's not marked as
>      read-only (writable:false) then a new property called foo is added
>      directly to myObject, resulting in a shadowed property.
> 2. If a foo is
>      found higher on the [[Prototype]] chain, but it's marked as read-only
>      (writable:false), then both the setting of that existing property as
>      well as the creation of the shadowed property on myObject are
>      disallowed. If the code is running in strict mode, an error will be
>      thrown. Otherwise, the setting of the property value will silently be
>      ignored. Either way, no shadowing occurs.
> 3. If a foo is found higher on
>      the [[Prototype]] chain and it's a setter (see Chapter 3), then the
>      setter will always be called. No foo will be added to (aka, shadowed
>      on) myObject, nor will the foo setter be redefined. Most developers
>      assume that assignment of a property ([[Put]]) will always result in
>      shadowing if the property already exists higher on the [[Prototype]]
>      chain, but as you can see, that's only true in one (#1) of the three
>      situations just described.
>
> If you want to shadow foo in cases #2 and #3, you cannot use =
>   assignment, but must instead use Object.defineProperty(..) (see
>   Chapter 3) to add foo to myObject.