# Create object where every property and subproperty is only writable once

Tags: javascript, node.js, immutability, immutable.js, es6-proxy

Is there a way to create an object with Javascript, where every property on the object is only writable once, and not modifiable after first write?

All I can of is a proxy object, that has hooks on assignment, ~something~ like this:

```
var p = new Proxy({}, {
    set: function(target, property, value, receiver){
      Object.defineProperty(target, property, {
           value: value,
           writable: false
       })
    }
});
```

But Proxy is expensive to use, and not available in all the JS engines I need to support. Is there someway to achieve this without using Proxy?

This is for a library. And I want to do the immutability legwork on the behalf of the user and to prevent the user from falling into certain traps, by using immutability.

*I want to create an immutable object, but I want the object to be extensible. However, any extension to the object, I want to be an immutable property.*

**note:** Object.freeze() does not allow an object to be extensible after the fact, which won't work for my use case.

Here is an example:

```
let foo = {bar: 3};
foo.bar = 2; // should fail

foo.x = 1; // ok
foo.x = 2; // should fail

foo.y = {}; // ok
foo.y.z = 5; // ok
foo.y.z = 3; // should fail
```

Comment: note that if I wanted every subproperty of the target to have the same thing going on, I would have to recursively call a function that does the work in the example in the original question.

Comment: By "writable once" do you mean that you write the object and the object cannot be modified following declaration? You should be able to use approaches at [How to detect when a JavaScript object variable is accessed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41405080/how-to-detect-when-a-javascript-object-variable-is-accessed/) to return a specific value for each property of the object using `Proxy`. What is the application?

Comment: it's a test harness, there are child blocks which inherit a property from parent blocks...but I don't want two siblings blocks to affect each other, etc.

Comment: Have you tried using `Object.freeze()`?

Comment: Object.freeze() does not allow an object to be extensible after the fact.

Comment: How will the two child blocks affect each other? What do you mean by "extensible after the fact"?

Comment: "not extensible after the fact" is => 'use strict'; var x = {}; Object.freeze(x); x.foo = 'bar' => error

Comment: 2 child blocks could affect each other or interact, if they can access and modify the same data. I want to minimize the possibility of that.

Comment: Viewing your code example, the first concept that considered was using `Promise`, `.addEventListener()` or a jQuery method to perform a task at most once. Later, if you decide to do so, you can return a new `Promise`, attach and dispatch the event again, or add and call specific jQuery methods on an object again

Comment: well attaching properties to an object should be synchronous right? so no need for events or promises? I am not entirely sure what you mean, would need to see a code sample.

Comment: `const p = Promise.resolve({abc:123})` cannot be changed. Though you can chain `.then()` to `p` to do stuff with the returned object. You can define a constant variable that exists only inside an event handler, dispatch the event at most once using `{once:true}` parameter of `.addEventListener()`, where a `CustomEvent` with `detail` set to the object is defined and dipatched to the object. Use a queue to perform N tasks at most N times, where the object exists only within a queued function. If you do not want the object to be able to be modified or deleted you can use `const` declaration.

Comment: yeah I guess an object where you are only supposed to use getters and setters, and setters can only be called once for a certain property.

Comment: Then use `Proxy`. There are probably several approaches which can meet requirement.

Comment: yeah Proxy is expensive and not sure if it's available in all the JS engines I want to use

Comment: Then use `const` declarations, since you are already using `let`. `const o = \`{
  "abc":123}\`` cannot be changed or deleted but can be accessed `JSON.parse(o)`